# MySQL LAST_INSERT_ID() with INSERT INTO tablea SELECT FROM tableb

Tags: mysql, lastinsertid, insert-select

Is it possible to update the *source* table with the LAST_INSERT_ID from the *target* table?

```
INSERT INTO `target` SELECT `a`, `b` FROM `source`
```

The *target* table has an auto increment key *id* which I would like to store in the *source* table for further usage.

Would save me a lot of computing power if something like this would be possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after executing:

```
INSERT INTO `target` SELECT `a`, `b` FROM `source`
```

Call an update on the `source` table as below:

```
UPDATE `source` 
SET field_name = LAST_INSERT_ID() 
WHERE col_name_x = some_value_or_expression
```

Change column names and where conditions and then execute it.

Comment: This works only for one entry, the UPDATE writes the first generated id to all entries, but I would need to have the correct id for each entry.

Comment: Insert always generates a single id. So for each of the unique insert, you have to use that specific id, to update its related data only. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` gives the latest inserted id, in single, only. To update multiple records you should have multiple inserts and a trigger as well, if I am thinking correct.